# HTML/CSS two adjacent search boxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a search bar like one would find on yelp. Two bars centered side by side. Per the code below I cannot get them to center. My thought was to create two columns and have them side side by side,one pulled right and the other left, but I am not having much luck. Any advice?

```
<HTML>
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 portfolio-item">
           <div class="input-group" display="inline">
                <input id="searchone" name="search" type="search" value="<?php echo $search_word;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 portfolio-item">
           <div class="input-group" display="inline">
                <input id="searchtwo" name="search" type="search" value="<?php echo $search_word;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn" name="submit" type="submit">
                    <span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" name="submit"></span>
                </button>    
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

```
 <CSS>
.row .col-sm-5 .input-group .form-control{
width:300px;
float:center;}
```

Comment: `center` is not a valid property for `float`.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 portfolio-item">
        <div class="input-group" display="inline">
            <input id="searchone" name="search" type="search" value="<?php echo $search_word;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-1 portfolio-item">
        <div class="input-group" display="inline">
            <input id="searchtwo" name="search" type="search" value="<?php echo $search_word;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn" name="submit" type="submit"> <span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" name="submit"></span>

                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/k3dkrwzy/1/)